# Writing 'Image.Image.paste()' to new file

Tags: python, discord.py

I need to paste first picture on second and save new picture as new file. How I can do it? My not-working code in the bottom.

```
main_path="J:/DS_bot/"
FFP_path=os.path.join(main_path, 'User_image/')
WFP_path=os.path.join(main_path, 'Results/')
FFP = os.path.join(FFP_path, filename)
WFP=os.path.join(WFP_path, filename)
MFP='J:/DS_bot/Mat/ERd3Wu5UhBc.jpg'
mat = Image.open(MFP)
with open(WFP, 'wb') as file:
    Image.Image.paste(mat, resize(FFP))
    file.write(mat)
```

P.S. If I use `mat.show()` I can see result,but I can't send it by discord bot and can't save it on my pc. Correct my code and post it near, k?

P.S. 2 I getting this error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'JpegImageFile'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see anything wrong but I think you can save the image without using the `open` method.
Also, you can paste on your `mat` image and save it as another image with `save`

```py
# I consider 'resize' function works properly
mat.paste(resize(FFP))
mat.save(WFP)
```

If you want to send the image in discord using `discord.py` you can use [this method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-upload-an-image)

```py
await channel.send(file=discord.File(WFP))
```

Comment: Ty for feedback, but WFP stands for "Writing Full Path", so, it's not a file) I want to save new image in this directory. If it's unreal (i don't think so) I need just for send message with it

Comment: @LegendaryHunter Both save method for image and File in discord accept the path as an argument (Tbh I'm not sure if the path object works but the string path always works)

Comment: Ty u so much!!! All working. You can add my bot to ur server by following this link)
https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?&775664928572964865=CLID&scope=bot&permissions=8